# Does anybody know the Quanta of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I am trying to find out how to entangle electrons and change their energy levels. Does anybody know how to change the energy levels in the electron?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Electrons don't have energy levels, so it's difficult to understand what you are trying to get at.

Comment: The electron would have to be in a bound system, such as an atom or a molecule, in order to have energy levels.  Free electrons can only have momentum and intrinsic properties.